# how to make login page as default page with angular

Tags: angular

I am a beginner in Angular, and I work on a template with [Nebular](http://akveo.com/ngx-admin/?theme=cosmic&utm_source=github&utm_medium=ngx_admin_readme&utm_campaign=themes#/pages/tables/smart-table).  Our authentication page (login) does not exist in the folder src, but in the folder node_modules, and I want to make the login page appears first when I open my interface, but I could not achive it. When I try to generate a new login component in the src folder, I found many problems that I didn't understand.

Comment: Do you try following documentation, it should help?  https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/install-based-on-starter-kit#install-based-on-starter-kit

Comment: You want to achive that when the application loads, the login page is shown and when you logged in you get to your normal template? Is this correct? Just asking because your question is bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In src/app/app-routing.module.ts,

change

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },`
```

in to

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the routing file of your apps `app.routes.ts`.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
 { 
   path: '', 
   redirectTo: '/your-login-url', 
   pathMatch: 'full' 
 }
]
```